# Fetch Reference MongoDB Driver 2.7.0

Tags: .net, mongodb, join, mongodb-.net-driver

Due to memory limitations I was forced to remove my datapoints from my sensors from an array into individual documents. I decided to use `MongoDBRef` Objects in my code to "join" the collections back together. I can create and write those `MongoDBRef` objects just fine into the database, and I can retrieve them, too.
But I want to now use the function to follow the reference as it is described [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_FetchDBRef.htm). However `MongoDatabase` is a legacy class and obsolete at this point, and the new interface `IMongoDatabase` doesn't implement the function.
I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877073/mongodb-best-practice-for-referencing) and that function in the answer also doesn't exist anymore.
Do I have to create an extra query myself from the data in the `MongoDBRef` object or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you'll have to create an extra query yourself.

A way to do this is by creating an extension method like this

```
public static TDocument FetchDBRefAs<TDocument>(this MongoDBRef dbRef, IMongoDatabase database)
{
     var collection = database.GetCollection<TDocument>(dbRef.CollectionName);

     var query = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", dbRef.Id);
     return collection.Find(query).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or the Async edition

```
 public static async Task<TDocument> FetchDBRefAsAsync<TDocument>(this MongoDBRef dbRef, IMongoDatabase database)
 {
     var collection = database.GetCollection<TDocument>(dbRef.CollectionName);

     var query = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", dbRef.Id);
     return await (await collection.FindAsync(query)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 }
```

which can be called like this

```
var referencedEntity = entity.ReferencedEntity.FetchDBRefAs<T>(this.database))
```

Where entity looks like

```
public class Entity
{
       [BsonId]
       [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string RandomProperty { get; set; }
       public MongoDBRef ReferencedEntity { get; set; }    
}
```